# Align inputs in different td horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to align 2 inputs in 2 different `td` tag to align horizontally. Moreover, when `input` has been appended into `td`, it will cover the `td` text

[image]

There are 2 cases:

- When both of `td` have text or empty, then everything is OK.
- When one of the 2 `td` has text, they do not align on same line

This is my source code I have tried: https://jsfiddle.net/oc8Lgm3y/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add `vertical-align:bottom;` to the `td,th`.

You can check the source code here: https://jsfiddle.net/k1gapfmq/

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 8px;
}

input[name=^='product'] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[image: html table]